# Visual Studio says, "Unable to read the project file" when opening a project from Source-Gear Vault

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sourcegear-vault

I am using Visual Studio Express (v4.0.30319) singing to the tune of Visual Basic, and I'm using Source-Gear for my source control Visual Studio integration.

When I open a project I have to do it via the source control menu, and when it opens I get a warning message: "Unable to read the project file 'RemotingClasses.vbproj'."

After clicking the okay button, everything seems to work fine with the padlocks and checking out files, but I really don't like that I can't open a project from the splash screen, and that error box looks really bad in front of clients, who are inclined to panic at the very sight of the "E" word (error, that is)

...Fatal or not ^_^

Can I get rid of it?

Comment: Source Gear doesn't list Visual Studio Express on its [compatibility list](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/documentation/compatibility_chart.html). Perhaps that is part of the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source Gear is not compatible with Visual Studio Express